# What is Fuse.io for?

Tags: network

I read that Fuse.io is a DPoS blockchain on the top of Ethereum, apparently to improve payment performance.

What is Fuse? What is its purpose?

If it is on the top of Ethereum, how payments may be faster or cheaper than Ethereum payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuse is on its own sidechain. Currently you can do about 10,000 transactions with just 1 Fuse token on fusenet and is much much faster than eth payments. You can also deploy solidity contracts just as you would on Eth Mainnet. With Fuse Studio you can easily create your own token and add plugin functions to it. Fuse also has Fusewallet for iOS and Android Phones.

New Fuse tokens are generated at 5% per year evenly distributed between validator nodes every block (about every 5 seconds) and validator node minimum stake is currently 100k Fuse tokens.